# fail to find favicon.ico in my root folder

Tags: php, html, css

I have added an icon for my webpages i.e. favicon.ico few months ago. Now I have removed that file from my server. Still when I test my website at [www.webpagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140303_T8_E85/1/details/) it is showing 404 errors for that favicon.ico. I am new to web designing, what could be the problem?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I can't see this line in your source code:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png" />
```

or

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

or

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://http://www.ludhianaweddingvendors.com/favicon.ico" />
```

I'm sure you have uploaded the file, but...Have you written the reference?